# Choose "safe" section of DDR memory in ZC702 board

Tags: memory, xilinx, addressing, ddr

I can not fully understand what section of the available external memory is safe to assign for a VDMA on the ZC702 board. I need to dedicate 4MB of memory for the three frames (640*480* 4bytes * 3 frames aligned memory). According to [UG585](http://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/user_guides/ug585-Zynq-7000-TRM.pdf) 
in Chapter4 table4-1 page 113,

[image]

it is clear that I should not use any memory for the VDMA in the 0x4000_0000 to 0xFDFF_FFFF. But which of the 0x0000_0000 to0x3FFF_FFFF would be the most "safe" to dedicate for my frames? Does it matter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to me that 0x0010_0000 to 0x3FFF_FFFF is the range to choose from.  This is listed as "accessible to all interconnect masters".  4MB is 0x0040_0000 of addresses - it won't even fit below 0x0010_0000.